# Nginx S3 proxy: Attempt to serve index.html on the first 404

Tags: nginx, redirect, amazon-s3, proxy, nginx-config

I have a really simple setup, I just want nginx to act a webserver for S3.

Meaning that if it hits a folder instead of returning `key not found` from S3 I want it to return the `index.html` of that possible folder.

Chrome does this automatically, but I am using it for a Python Pip repo, which doesn't automatically try the index.html.

```
location / {
    aws_sign;
    proxy_pass http://[my bucket].s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

All the answer that I've been able to find revolve around serving files instead, but that's not what I want. What I want is for nginx to retry the proxy with a different `[url]` namely `[url]/index.html`.

Comment: S3 does this automatically (no Nginx or other front-end needed) when you use the web site hosting endpoint rather than the REST endpoint, after configuring index document support: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The issue was that the proxy had to be inside the company network only, which as far as I can tell is not possible with S3 based hosting.

The solution I eventually ended up with was just writing my own proxy as there just isn't a simple way to do it with nginx (which didn't break in some use-case).